# Automating Line Creation with Multiple Points

Tags: arcpy, point, line, arcgis-10.3

I have a feature class that has over 1500 points in it. I then need to create line segments from these points based on an ID number. For example points 1-6 have the ID 1, points 7-12 ID 2 etc. 
Each point has an easting, northing and elevation and PointID that I want to keep as attributes in the polyline file. 
Here is how my point data is structured

[image]

And I want my output to look like this, although continues with the rest of the point information associated with each line.

[image]

I want to be able to automate this with python, but am unsure about how to structure the code because there can be anywhere from 3-6 points associated with each ID that need to make a line. I currently do this manually and would love to be able to create the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are not aware of the tool [points to line](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000003s000000)! The line ID would be your `CULV_ID`. Would `PTID` be the order of your points? Having used that tool to create the lines you would to write some code that reads for each ID and build the fields to transfer the information over.

Comment: I had not heard of that thank you! I'm relatively new to python would you potentially be able to point me in the right direction of samples for reading each ID to build fields to transfer the information over?